# Is it bad practice to have a `try-catch` inside a method?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try 
            {
                checkifStringNull(string check)
                Clean();
            }
            catch(ArgumentNullException msg)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg.Message);
            }


        }
        public static int Clean()
        {
            List<string> errorLog = new List<string>();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
            {
                try
                {
                        dir.Delete(true);
                }

                catch(System.UnauthorizedAccessException msg)
                {
                        code = 5;
                        errorLog.Add(String.Concat(dir.FullName," ", code ," ", msg.Message));
                        Console.WriteLine("Error Removing the directory: {0}", dir.FullName);

                }
                catch(System.IO.IOException msg)
                {
                        code = 5;
                        errorLog.Add(String.Concat(dir.FullName," ", code ," ", msg.Message));
                        Console.WriteLine("Error Removing the directory: {0}", dir.FullName);

                }
            }
        }

        public static void checkifStringNull(string check)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(check))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(String.Format("String can't be null"));
            }

        }
```

I've got a method that deletes the sub directories for a specific path. Is it okay if I have my **try catch inside the method**? The reason is I want direct access to the variable(directory) inside the loop that threw the exception and for me it's more organized. If I were to remove the code from the method and place it inside main, it would look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    try 
    {
        checkifStringNull(string check)
        List<string> errorLog = new List<string>();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
    {
        try
        {
                dir.Delete(true);
        }

        catch(System.UnauthorizedAccessException msg)
        {
                code = 5;
                errorLog.Add(String.Concat(dir.FullName," ", code ," ", msg.Message));
                Console.WriteLine("Error Removing the directory: {0}", dir.FullName);

        }
        catch(System.IO.IOException msg)
        {
                code = 5;
                errorLog.Add(String.Concat(dir.FullName," ", code ," ", msg.Message));
                Console.WriteLine("Error Removing the directory: {0}", dir.FullName);

        }
    }

    }
    catch(ArgumentNullException msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Message);
    }


}
```

I have a try-catch embedded inside another try-catch, is that considered bad practice or inefficient?

Comment: Strictly spoken, try-catch is *always* inside a method ;-). More pragmatically: Catch where you can handle it. That's the only rule. Nested try/catch blocks are fine.

Comment: Extend your question to its logical conclusion: "Every exception ever no matter how deep has to make it to main()." Does that help answer it for you?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - Many thanks for the explanation, and I do catch and handle what to do inside the method.

Comment: @John3136 - Never thought of it that way, but you're so right :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally - no issue, you can throw or catch anywhere and everywhere **if there is a reason** to do that and you're actually doing something in a `catch` that other `catch`es aren't doing or if the `throw` is actually needed, usually to interrupt the current flow

In your example you have a loop that deletes folders. If one certain folder doesn't delete you may still want to continue deleting, so you can check for IOException or UnauthorizedAccessException (no need of `System.` prefix, put `using System;` above the class)

That, however can't be said for your `ArgumentNullException` - if you have a condition you can just check the condition and avoid throwing an exception. Throwing an exception is not very high-performance operation and should generally be avoided when there is a low-cost alternative, such as `if`:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(theString)){
  doSomeWork();
} else {
  didNotDoTheWork();// such as Console.WriteLine("Error: theString is empty");
}
```

Another mild issue with your sample is that you're catching two different exceptions but doing the exact same thing. Instead you can do this:

```
try
{
  dir.Delete(true);
} 
catch(Exception x)
{
  if (x is UnauthorizedAccessException || x is IOException){
    Console.WriteLine("Error Removing the directory: {0}", dir.FullName);
  }
  else throw;
}
```

with C# 6.0 you (VS 2015) you can also do:

```
try
{
  dir.Delete(true);
} 
catch(Exception x) when (x is UnauthorizedAccessException || x is IOException)
{ 
  Console.WriteLine("Error Removing the directory: {0}", dir.FullName); 
}
```

Comment: In the last example, shouldn't that be `catch(Exception x) when ` rather than if?

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing wrong with having `try-catch` in a method, and there's nothing wrong with having `try-catch` inside another `try-catch`.

The only thing that matters, is whose job it is to handle exceptions.

Sometimes you have a method whose only job is attempt to perform a task, and not deal with unusual conditions. That method shouldn't catch exceptions.

Other times you have a method which you want to deal with many or even all exceptional cases, and not return control otherwise. This method would catch exceptions, and might have a lot of code to do so, possibly with nested `try-catch`blocks.

Real life works the same way. Sometimes you want someone to try and get you coffee, but if it doesn't work out (the place is closed, the line was really long) they should just come back and you'll deal with it. Other times you want them to go out for coffee, and not come back empty handed. Both are perfectly legitimate; it just depends on what you want to happen.  It's completely a case by case basis.

A lot of beginners (and beyond!) make the mistake, of thinking they should catch all exceptions and never throw one. That would be like a babysitter, thinking it was their job to handle any unusual situation that comes up. Probably true for spilled soda. But when the curtains are on fire, you might prefer the exception be handled by someone else.

Comment: I like the coffee explanation, but thanks. Much appreciated!